# Python: How to request integers in simple webapp

Tags: python, html, flask, request

long time listener first time caller.

I'm trying to build a basic webapp whilst following along with the steps in Headfirst Python by Paul Barry. My webapp is supposed to remove a number of characters from the end of a word then return those characters as a string.

I have the function working fine at the shell but am having trouble requesting an integer from the HTML form, receiving the following error.

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

I hope this will be enough information for somebody to give me some help, I did try to post the '/entry' HTML but I could not figure out how to format it on here correctly.

Thanks for reading.
Glen

**Here is my functions code:**

```
def remove_chars(word:str, n:int) -> str:
    return str('pynative'[n:])
```

**Here is my webapps code:**

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from remove_chars import remove_chars
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/remove_chars_4_web', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> str:
    word = request.form['word']
    characters = request.form['characters']
    return str(remove_chars(word, characters))
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to remove_chars on the web!')
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: All data submitted through forms will be *strings*…!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I need to convert the submitted string back to an integer? Should this happen in my webapps code or in the function it calls? Cheers

Comment: That would be the task of your `do_search` function; for all intents and purposes it's the *controller*, whose job it is to handle incoming requests and any peculiarities of them and pass the necessary data into the "model", in this case `remove_chars`. I.e. just `int(request.form['characters'])`…

Comment: Thanks that is perfect! How do I mark this question as answered please?